# What is Serialization and why? [Unity3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I've been learning some new stuff with Unity lately and I see people making private variables (movement speed, etc), and serializing them. Is there a point to this as opposed to making variables public?

Comment: Making a variable public essentially makes it available to other c# code running in the same process. When a variable is serialized you can do a lot more with it, e.g. send it over a network (e.g. to your browser or a web client) or store it on disk or in a database.

Comment: ... or expose a variable into Unity Inspector. Note that you must add [System.Serializable] declaration upon class (which is then used as a variable), exposing it in the inspector.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [API -> Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)? In short two use cases: Expose and adjust values and references via the Inspector and **save** those into your scene and prefab assets without the need to make everything `public` => encapsulation